# For fully 3D isometric games, is it better to turn the camera 45°? Or have the environment be rotated 45°?

Tags: isometric

For fully 3D isometric games, is it better to turn the camera 45°? Or have the environment be rotated 45°? I'm asking because, after trying to tilt the camera 45°, the movement code had to be a bit more complex to account for the angle. I'm not sure if it will cause more issues down the line with NPC movement, etc. So perhaps it's better to just turn everything else other than the player 45°.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made two isometric games in two different programming languages before, and I usually find it way easier to handle the game mechanics (including things like NPC movement) as if the game was completely orthogonal until it gets to visualizing it. In your terms, that would mean that the camera is at an angle and the environment is axis-aligned. That makes a ton of things a lot easier to handle. An entity moving forward, for example, simply increases its x coordinate by its velocity, instead of increasing both its x coordinate and its y coordinate by its `velocity * Math.sin(Math.PI / 4)`. Or do I need to use the cosine for y? Or perhaps -cosine?

You said that making the world axis-aligned but tilting the camera makes "the movement code a bit more complex". I don't really see why that would be the case. But there are lots of ways to do movement in an isometric game. It is very well possible that your particular solution is indeed more fit for a rotated world. For example, when you move the player with the thumb stick, then you need to rotate the input vector by the camera rotation to make the input aligned with the view. But that doesn't mean it's the *only* possible solution for your game. So if you told us more about your movement problems in a new question, we might be able to help you with finding a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that it really shouldn't matter, use whatever you find most convenient.

The longer answer is that converting between the two is fairly simple trigonometry, so pick a coordinate system and orientation that make the game code cleanest.

Personally, I'd keep the world axis-aligned and have a "focus point" or "look at point" also in axis-aligned space.

Then just position your camera at `focus + (+x, +y, +z)` and point the camera at `focus`.

[Obviously you can use ± `x` and `z` to control which corner you're looking from]

But even if you chose to have the world rotated 45 degrees, the world will have it's own transform (matrix) and you could multiple any axis-aligned position by that matrix to transform it from "axis space" to "skewed world space", so again... Not onerous.